# Dealing with fungus and molds

Tags: diseases, fungus, mold

I'm interested in ways to deal (remove) fungus from spaces used to germinate seeds. I noticed that hydrogen peroxide, isopropylacohol and baking soda. Are these just for fungus or mold too?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you defined "spaces". Hydrogen peroxide is effective as a disinfectant on surfaces but won't kill molds and fungi that are systemic or have any other place to hide where the hydrogen peroxide can't readily get to. Also, it's a disinfectant, but that doesn't mean it's 100% effective against any organism. I doubt baking soda would kill anything, I think you mean soda crystals. Isopropyl and soda would both work for surfaces as well, as would bleach. I would guess bleach is the strongest. Vinegar sprayed followed by hydrogen peroxide sprayed works well too. Have to apply separately.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW you could start seedlings in a moist mixture of naturally anti-fungal [coconut coir](https://amzn.to/2pvQPxN), and then once they get established use a [fertilizer](https://amzn.to/2oBuK0g) or other stuff that contains beneficial fungi to hopefully out-compete fusarium and other types of fungi.

Answer (score 1):

Bleach would help, but you would need fresh air if you use it, and not mix it with anything. It could heat up and do just about anything, like a little dish liquid can turn in into a very strong ammonia, that is dangerous to your lungs.

You can mix Comet or Ajax to bleach to help disinfect anything.

Something to know it when you get a wilt fungus in the ground you would need to clear the ground and treat it with bleach. There is something called a Bordeaux solution of copper sulfate and lime. You shout look it up, because it will help your garden.
Copper Sulfate can clear up from slime from water, and is used to kill the fungus growing in the water by products used to make dog food. It is poisonous to fish, and more likely to your pets that eat the dry dog food.